# How can I migrate a VMWare image from my PC to OSX VMWare Fusion?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualization

How can I migrate a VMWare folder/image from my Windows PC to OSX VMWare Fusion?

When I copy the files across there is nothing to import; none of the VMWare files are selectable/clickable.

Comment: The import function requires a OVF or OVA file. That's why it doesn't recognize the raw files. tbenz9 has the correct answer.

Comment: I found out that the portability between WMWare tools are excellent, no need to export between WMWare products on different platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend exporting the VM in Windows as an OVA or OVF.  This is a container format that holds all the settings and data.  It is a universal VM format that is frequently used to move VMs between products.  Once it's an OVA/OVF you can move it to your OSX computer and import it into VMWare Fusion.  You can actually import it into Virtualbox, or just about any other virtualization program if you want.

[Docs to Import OVF](http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.fusion.help.doc/GUID-275EF202-CF74-43BF-A9E9-351488E16030.html)

[VMWare OVF tool docs](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out that just copying the folder from WMWare on the PC to the Mac OSX was fine. It just needed to be bundled. I achieved bundeling by adding a .wmwarevm to the copied folder name. To add the image/bundle in WMWare Fusion I just clicked the bundle and it was added successful.

Comment: Even though that will usually work going the OVA route is still recommended. If the underlying hardware of source and target hosts machine are very different just copying the VM may corrupt the VM when the new machine tries to boot it. Generating the OVA also ensures that any snapshots are in a well-defined state. That is something you can't guarantee on a raw copy.